# Postgres - aggregate minutes to hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I need some assistance with PostgresSQL. I am trying to group some records (5-, 10-, 15-, 20-, etc) into 60-minute intervals.

*What i need is to GROUP BY and AVG the minute values within a given hour to the respective hour.*

```
SELECT id, value, 
extract(year from GDDP.timestamp) as YEAR, 
extract(month from GDDP.timestamp) as MONTH,
extract(day from GDDP.timestamp) as DAY, 
extract(hour from GDDP.timestamp) as "HOUR",
extract(minute from GDDP.timestamp) as MINUTE,

FROM GDDP

WHERE value > 0 AND 
GDDP.timestamp  BETWEEN '2016-07-01 00:00:00' and '2016-12-31 23:55:00'

ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR
```

Currently, this is the result of the query above:

```
id | value | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 100   | 2016 | 07    | 01  | 1    | 05
2  | 200   | 2016 | 07    | 01  | 1    | 10
3  | 100   | 2016 | 07    | 01  | 1    | 15
4  | 300   | 2016 | 07    | 01  | 1    | 20
5  | 200   | 2016 | 07    | 01  | 1    | 25
6  | 500   | 2016 | 07    | 01  | 1    | 30
```

But, I would like the result to look like this:

```
id | value  | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOUR
---------------------------------------
1  | 233.3  | 2016 | 07    | 01  | 1
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Can you explain your algorithm better?  "GROUP BY and AVG the minute values within a given hour" suggests that you're going to average 15 and 20 for 123, producing 1 in the output; average 10 and 25 for 342, producing 2 in the output; and average 15 and 30 for 567, producing 3 in the output.  That doesn't make sense, so it must be wrong.  How instead do you mean to get the output hours of 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: @rd_nielsen i've edited the table to be more realistic. Essentially, i need to average the **values** from each row with the same MONTH, DAY, HOUR as a rollup to the respective hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the aggregation function `avg()` in groups by `year, month, day, hour`

```
SELECT 
    min(id) as id,
    avg(value) as value, 
    extract(year from gddp.timestamp) as year, 
    extract(month from gddp.timestamp) as month,
    extract(day from gddp.timestamp) as day, 
    extract(hour from gddp.timestamp) as hour
FROM gddp
WHERE value > 0 
AND gddp.timestamp  BETWEEN '2016-07-01 01:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 01:23:00'
GROUP BY year, month, day, hour
ORDER BY year, month, day, hour;

 id |        value         | year | month | day | hour 
----+----------------------+------+-------+-----+------
  1 | 233.3333333333333333 | 2016 |     7 |   1 |    1
(1 row)
```